# Replace 5mm LED with High Power without changing the circuitboard

Tags: power, led

I would like to know if I can replace the LED on my radar detector remote controller with a high power one without changing the circuit board components.

Attached is the board and I'm looking to replace the "Alert LED" with this one:

- Brand: Chanzon
- Power: 3 Watt (Max)
- Emitting Color: Natural White (4000K-4500K)
- Recommended Current: 600mA
- Forward Voltage: 3.0-3.4V
- Luminous Flux: 260-280LM

[image: Schematic of radar detector remote controller]

Comment: You will be unlikely to find a direct replacement for the led without knowing how much current is available from the source detector, **without adding on a small circuit**. That relay isnt necessary, but you could put an opto transistor in parallel with the existing led, and a small power transistor and regulator as a led driver.

Answer (score 0):

> Current: 600 mA. Forward voltage: 3.0 - 3.4 V.

[image]

[No](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF).

Comment: Im trying to avoid doing the following as it will be way to bright in my eyes at night.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIqHD.jpg

is there an easy way to wire just one of those led to the current circuitboard?

Comment: You have lost me. Your question is about installing a very bright light. Your comment is about making it less bright. Ehm, ...

Comment: The image in the second comment uses 3 LEDs. I wanted to see if i can get away to  use just 1 in place of the current "alert led from the firs schematic" and without making an addition circuitboard.

Comment: I don't know. We don't know what's feeding the RJ11 connector.

Comment: Ill make measurements shortly and post them. (need to find something to trigger the detector)

Comment: it gets 2.79 volts from the radar detector.

Comment: Can you recommend a led that can be a direct replacement to the alert one that is bright and visible in daylight?